# Swift lottie animation does not play some json files that play on the android

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I tried to make ios app that play animation json exported from Adobe After Effect using bodymovin using swift and lottie.
I make android app that have the same functions.
On the android there is no problem but using the same json files I cannot play json animation on the ios.

On the ios, my app work properly for another json files from sample project or lottie.

If there are any people that have experience on this, please help me out.

```
animationView = LAAnimationView.animationNamed("New_Anim2") 
animationView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 250) 
animationView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
animationView?.backgroundColor = .white
self.view.addSubview(animationView!)        
animationView?.play()
```

full source code and json files link: [enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6o25Ypr0hZuSUhtVk1MS1R0eVU)

Comment: did you get solution above issue? if you have please share with me.

Comment: Are you aware of this whacky issue ?  https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-ios/issues/498

Comment: @Fattie I get lottie file link via google meet chat from mr. designer . I download lottie animation json file using this link and imported in fresh demo app. it worked on create fresh demo app but when I am adding this json file to my existing project. it doesn't worked.

Comment: @NarendraJagne designer must ZIP the file before send to you

Comment: @Fattie he send me json zip file but does't worked

Answer (score 0):

I was working on an app recently with Lottie check out this way of using animations btw u have to copy the json file in project document outline and not in asset folder.

```
let animationView = LOTAnimationView(name: "splash_loader")
        self.AnimationView.addSubview(animationView)
        self.AnimationView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
        animationView.sizeToFit()
       // animationView.sizeThatFits(AnimationView.frame.size)
        animationView.play{ (finished) in
            // Do Something
            animationView.removeFromSuperview()
            self.AnimationView.willRemoveSubview(animationView)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all put json file into your project:

```
let jsonName = "jsonFileName"
let animation = Animation.named(jsonName)

// Load animation to AnimationView
let animationView = AnimationView(animation: animation)
animationView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)

// Add animationView as subview
view.addSubview(animationView)

// Play the animation
animationView.play()
```